# Reactive UI with Datagrids

Tags: wpf, datagrid, reactive-programming

Currently my RadDatagrid1 has a Cell_click action for the RadDatagrid1, and when a ClientName is selected, that client info is projected in DataGrid2. 
code within Mouse Double Click:

```
private void Cell_click(object sender, GridViewSelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Var Details = (from info in contacts
                  where info.ClientName = sender.CurrentCell.ToString()
                  select new {info.ClientName, info.ClientAddress, Info.ClientNumber});
    DataGrid2.ItemsSource = Details.ToList();
}
```

This is currently what i have but, it should be a reactive UI.
An example of reactitve UI i was told to look at was this in the GridViewModel:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Forename, x => x.Surname, x => x.City, (p1, p2, p3) => Unit.Default).Subscribe(x => Filter());
```

But that doesn't quite make sense to me. If I could get guidance and tips how to convert this to reactive UI please.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to Reactive UI and my experience so far has been through trial and error, due to the lack of documentation. So my method below might not be correct.

Make sure you have a ViewModel backing your WPF control (see [this page](https://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fundamentals/reactive-object/))

Your ViewModel should look something like:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject {
    // ClientInfo type is the type of object you want to bind to the DataGrid
    private ClientInfo clientInfo;  

    public ClientInfo ClientInfo {
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref clientInfo, value); }
        get { return clientInfo; }
    }

    // Move contacts IEnumerable/IQueryable to your ViewModel
    private IQueryable<ClientInfo> contacts;

    public LoadInfo(string clientName) {
        ClientInfo = (from info in contacts
                  where info.ClientName = clientName
                  select new {info.ClientName, info.ClientAddress, Info.ClientNumber})
    }    
}
```

Make sure your View (the control class) implements `IViewFor<T>` where `T` is the type of your View Model. Bind views according to the documentation [here](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/binding/).

Do something like this for your View:

```
// Implement the methods on that interface, which I will not include below
public partial class View : IViewFor<ViewModel> { 

    private ICommand loadClientInfo;

    public View() { // constructor
        InitializeComponent(); // Don't forget this

        // Binds the data in your ViewModel with the ItemSource of your DataGrid
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ClientInfo, x => x.DataGrid2.ItemSource);
    }

    private void Cell_click(object sender, GridViewSelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.LoadInfo(sender.CurrentCell.ToString());
    }
}
```